# How to send multiple Json request and populate ReyclerView with the data

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-recyclerview

I am practicing building an android app for wordpress blog and what I basically want to do is to fetech the post title and it's author. I am able to get and display the post title without any hassles but what's giving headache is the post author.

This is the link of the json https://hmn.md/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

This are my codes

**PostItems**

```
public class PostItems implements Parcelable {
    private String post_title;
    private String post_author;

    public String getPost_title() {
        return post_title;
    }

    public void setPost_title(String post_title) {
        this.post_title = post_title;
    }



    public String getPost_author() {
        return post_author;
    }

    public void setPost_author(String post_author) {
        this.post_author = post_author;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.post_title);
        dest.writeString(this.post_author);
    }

    public PostItems() {
    }

    protected PostItems(Parcel in) {
        this.post_title = in.readString();
        this.post_author = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<PostItems> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PostItems>() {
        @Override
        public PostItems createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PostItems(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PostItems[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PostItems[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Part of PostList**

```
...
private void getData(){
         Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
         final ProDialoFrag dialoFrag = ProDialoFrag.newInstance();
         dialoFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");


         //Creating a json request
         jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
                 new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                         //Dismissing the progress dialog
                         if (dialoFrag != null ) {
                             dialoFrag.dismiss();
                         }
                         //calling method to parse json array
                         parseData(response);

                     }
                 },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         if (dialoFrag != null) {
                             dialoFrag.dismiss();
                         }
                         if (sthWrongAlert != null) {
                             sthWrongAlert.show();
                         }

                     }
                 }) {

         };

         //Creating request queue
         RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

         //Adding request to the queue
         requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

     }

     //This method will parse json data
     private void parseData(JSONArray array){
         Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

         mPostItemsList.clear();


         for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
             PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
             JSONObject jsonObject = null;
             try {
                 jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                 JSONObject postTitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                 postItem.setPost_title(postTitle.getString("rendered"));

                 JSONObject links = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                 JSONArray authorLink = links.getJSONArray("author");
                 String authorhref = authorLink.getJSONObject(0).getString("name")



                 postItem.setPostId(jsonObject.getString("link"));
             } catch (JSONException w) {
                 w.printStackTrace();
                 //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

             mPostItemsList.add(postItem);

         }
         adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());


     }
```

**PostAdapter**

```
      public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


     private static Context mContext;


     //List of posts
     private List<PostItems> mPostItems;

     private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
     private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;

     private int lastPosition = -1;


    public PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postItems, Context context) {
        super();

        //Getting all posts
        this.mPostItems = postItems;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


     @Override
     public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         if (isPositionItem(position))
             return VIEW_ITEM;
         return VIEW_PROG;
     }

     private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
        return position != getItemCount()-1;
     }



     @Override
     public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
             View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                     .inflate(R.layout.post_summ, parent, false);
             return new CardDetails(v);
         } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
             View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                     .inflate(R.layout.recyclerfooter, parent, false);
             return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
         }

         return null;
     }



     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

         if (holder instanceof CardDetails) {
             final PostItems postList = mPostItems.get(position);

             ((CardDetails) holder).postTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(postList.getPost_title()));
             ((CardDetails) holder).postAuthor.setText(postList.getPost_author());


         } else {
             ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
         }


     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount(){
         //Return the number of items in the data set
         return mPostItems.size();
     }


     public class CardDetails extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
         public TextView postTitle, postAuthor;

         public CardDetails (final View postView) {
             super(postView);
             postTitle = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
             postAuthor = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
         }

     }

     public  class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
         ProgressBar progressBar;
         public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
             super(footerView);
             progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

     }


 }
```

---

**My Current Solution**

```
 private void parseData(JSONArray array){
         Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");


         for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject jsonObject;
             try {
                 jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                 JSONObject postTitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                 String postT = postTitle.getString("rendered");
                 mPostTitle = postT;


                 JSONObject links = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                 JSONArray authorLink = links.getJSONArray("author");
                 authorhref = authorLink.getJSONObject(0).getString("href");


                 getAuthor();

             } catch (JSONException w) {
                 w.printStackTrace();
                 //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

         }


     }

     private void getAuthor() {
         Log.d(TAG, "getAuthor called");

         JsonObjectRequest authorRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(authorhref, null,
                 new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                         parseAuthor(response);
                     }
                 },
                 new Response.ErrorListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                     }
                 });

         authorRequest.setShouldCache(false);

         RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
         requestQueue.add(authorRequest);

     }

     private void parseAuthor (JSONObject object) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Parsing author");
         PostItems postItem = new PostItems();

         try {
             String authorname = object.getString("name");
             postItem.setPost_author(authorname);
             postItem.setPost_title(mPostTitle);
         } catch (JSONException w) {
             w.printStackTrace();
         }
         mPostItemsList.add(postItem);
         adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());
     }
```

The problem wih my solution is that all the posts titles are the same. To explain further,  the author names are what they are supposed to be, but all the post titles are the title of the last post.

Please do have any idea how I could fix this?

---

**After Applying kris larson's Answer**

**Part of PostFragment**

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment{

    private List<PostItems> mPostItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    // Nothing changed here, just added it so you will understand my code better
    ObservableRecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;


        public PostFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String title = getArguments().getString("title");
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
            //Initializing Views
            recyclerView = (ObservableRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_recycler);
            recyclerView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager);
            ...

    //This method will get data from the web api
        private void getData(){
            Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
            final ProDialoFrag dialoFrag = ProDialoFrag.newInstance();
            dialoFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");


            //Creating a json request
            jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                            //Dismissing the progress dialog
                            if (dialoFrag == null ) {
                                dialoFrag.dismiss();
                            }
                            //calling method to parse json array
                            parseData(response);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if (dialoFrag != null) {
                                dialoFrag.dismiss();
                            }
                            if (sthWrongAlert != null) {
                                sthWrongAlert.show();
                            }

                        }
                    }) {
                n Response.success(resp.result, entry);
                }
            };

            //Creating request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        }

        //This method will parse json data
        private void parseData(JSONArray array){
            Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

            for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject postTitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                    String title = postTitle.getString("rendered"));

                    JSONObject links = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                    JSONArray authorLink = links.getJSONArray("author");
                    String authorhref = authorLink.getJSONObject(0).getString("href");

                    PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
                    postItem.setPost_title(title);
                    postItem.setPostAuthorUrl(authorhref);
                    mPostItemsList.add(postItem);

                    if (adapter.getAuthor(authorhref) == null) {
                        getAuthor(authorhref);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException w) {
                    w.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            }
            adapter.setPostItems(mPostItemsList);


        }

        private void getAuthor (String authorhref) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getAuthor called");

            JsonObjectRequest authorRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(authorhref, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                            parseAuthor(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //Do nothing
                        }
                    });
            authorRequest.setShouldCache(false);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(authorRequest);
        }
        private void parseAuthor (JSONObject object) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Parsing auhor");
            try {
                JSONObject links = object.getJSONObject("_links");
                JSONArray self = links.getJSONArray("self");
                String href = self.getJSONObject(0).getString("href");

                String authorname = object.getString("name");
                adapter.putAuthor(href, authorname);
            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

**PostAdapter**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{



    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private static Context mContext;


    //List of posts
    private List<PostItems> mPostItems;

    //authors by url
    private Map<String, String> mAuthorMap;

    //don't forget to initialoze in adapter constructor
    mAuthorMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public void setPostItems(List<PostItems> postItems) {
        mPostItems = postItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void putAuthor(String url, String name) {
        mAuthorMap.put(url, name);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public String getAuthor(String url) {
        return mAuthorMap.get(url);
    }


   public PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postItems, Context context) {
       super();

       //Getting all posts
       this.mPostItems = postItems;
       this.mContext = context;
   }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionItem(position))
            return VIEW_ITEM;
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }

    private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
       return position != getItemCount()-1;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.post_summ, parent, false);
            return new CardDetails(v);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerfooter, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof CardDetails) {
            final PostItems postList = mPostItems.get(position);
            ((CardDetails) holder).postTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(postList.getPost_title()));

            String name = mAuthorMap.get(postList.getPostAuthorUrl());
            if (name != null) {
                ((CardDetails) holder).postAuthor.setText(name);
            }

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //Return the number of items in the data set
        return mPostItems.size();
    }





    public class CardDetails extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView postTitle, postAuthor;
        public ImageButton imageButton;

        public CardDetails (final View postView) {
            super(postView);
            postTitle = (TextView) postView

            .findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            postAuthor = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        }


    }

    public  class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
            super(footerView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


}
```

**Problems I am currently Having**

1. In PostFragment

   From line `if (adapter.getAuthor(authorhref) == null) {` AS is complaining that "cannot resolve method *getAuthor(Java.lang.String)*

   From line `adapter.setPostItems(mPostItemsList);` *Cannot resolve meethod 'setPostItems(java.util.List.com.example.postapp.PostItems>)'*

   From line `adapter.putAuthor(href, authorname);` *Cannot resolve method 'putAuthor(java.lang.String)'*
2. In PostAdapter

From line `mAuthorMap = new HashMap<>();` *'Unknown class mAuthorMap'* and also *`Identifier expected`* in the position of `>`

Methods `setPostItems`, `putAuthor`, `getAuthor` all saying *Method never used.

And in `parseAuthor` method, I didn't really understand what you were trying to do, it's as if you are trying to get the `"self"` array; though what I wanted is the author array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using `HttpURLConnection` and `AsyncTask`, you could make both requests in one background operation and have no problem.

But since it looks like you are committed to using Volley, I propose that you use a two-phase approach. In phase 1 you parse the posts and save the author urls for the post.  In phase 2, you add the author name to a map indexed by url.

- Have the `PostItem` contain the author url instead of the author name:

  ```
  public class PostItem implements Parcelable {
      private String post_title;
      private String post_author_url;
      // also change all the getters/setters/parceling etc.
  }
  ```

  (I made it PostItem -- singular -- because it's not a homogeneous collection of any kind.)
- Add a `Map` to your adapter to contain the author names:

  ```
      /** posts, which contain author url */
      private List<PostItem> mPostItems;

      /** authors by url */
      private Map<String, String> mAuthorMap;
  ```

  don't forget to initialize the author map in adapter constructor

  ```
  public PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postItems, Context context) {
      super();

      //Getting all posts
      this.mPostItems = postItems;
      this.mContext = context;
      this.mAuthorMap = new HashMap<>();
  }
  ```
- When you receive the posts:

  1. Parse the post item
  2. Make a `PostItem` with the title and the author url
  3. Add the `PostItem` to the adapter
  4. Ask the adapter for the author
  5. If author not found, start a new author request

     ```
         private void parseData(JSONArray array){

             Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

             // Collect all the PostItems and add to adapter all at once
             List<PostItem> postItems = new ArrayList<>();

             for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jsonObject;
                 try {
                     jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                     JSONObject postTitle = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                     String title = postTitle.getString("rendered");

                     JSONObject links = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                     JSONArray authorLink = links.getJSONArray("author");
                     String authorhref = authorLink.getJSONObject(0).getString("href");

                     PostItem postItem = new PostItem();
                     postItem.setPostTitle(title);
                     postItem.setPostAuthorUrl(authorhref);
                     postItems.add(postItem);

                     if (mAdapter.getAuthor(authorhref) == null) {
                         getAuthor(authorhref);
                     }

                 } catch (JSONException w) {
                     w.printStackTrace();
                     //Toast.makeText(this, "Error in parsing Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }

             mAdapter.setPostItems(postItems);
         }
     ```
- Notice I changed your `getAuthor` method to take a parameter (and not use a member variable):

  ```
          private void getAuthor(String authorhref) {
              ...
  ```
- When you receive the author, add it to the adapter

  ```
          private void parseAuthor (JSONObject object) {

              Log.d(TAG, "Parsing author");
              try {
                  JSONObject links = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                  JSONArray self = links.getJSONArray("self");
                  String href = authorLink.getJSONObject(0).getString("href");

                  String authorname = object.getString("name");
                  mAdapter.putAuthor(href, name);

              } catch (JSONException w) {
                  w.printStackTrace();
              }

         }
  ```
- Now here are the new adapter methods:

  ```
      public void setPostItems(List<PostItem> postItems) {
          mPostItems = postItems;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      public void putAuthor(String url, String name) {
          mAuthorMap.put(url, name);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      public String getAuthor(String url) {
          return mAuthorMap.get(url);
      }
  ```
- And `onBindViewHolder` is where it all comes together:

  ```
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

          if (holder instanceof CardDetails) {
              final PostItem postItem = mPostItems.get(position);
              ((CardDetails) holder).postTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(postItem.getPostTitle()));

              String name = mAuthorMap.get(postItem.getPostAuthorUrl());

              if (name != null) {
                  ((CardDetails) holder).postAuthor.setText(name);
              }
              // don't worry if author name is null, when it's retrieved
              // the adapter will be notified to refresh the list

          } else {
              ((ProgressViewHolder)  holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
          }
      }
  ```

---

EDIT:  Different way to get the author url without having to parse author JSON -> _links -> self[0] -> href

```
        // notice that authorhref is final
        private void getAuthor (final String authorhref) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getAuthor called");

            JsonObjectRequest authorRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(authorhref, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                        parseAuthor(authorhref, response);  // pass authorhref with response
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                });
                authorRequest.setShouldCache(false);
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                requestQueue.add(authorRequest);
            }

            private void parseAuthor (String authorhref, JSONObject object) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Parsing author");
                try {
                    String authorname = object.getString("name");
                    mAdapter.putAuthor(authorhref, name);

                } catch (JSONException w) {
                    w.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your answer. I have updated my question to reflect the changes made after applying your answer and the problems I got with it. Pleaese, can you take a look at it.

The reason why I avoided `HttpURLConnection` and `AsyncTask` is because I read somewhere of some unfixed bugs in `HttpURLConnection`.  However if `HttpURLConnection` and `AsyncTask` will fix the problem, I don't mind letting go of `Volley`.

Comment: Edited my answer.  Look at the section about `mAuthorMap`, I updated that section to be a little more precise.  Right now the statement `mAuthorMap = new HashMap<>();` is in the wrong place; fix that up and let's see what you have.

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, the only improvement is that the `mAuthorMap = new HashMap<>();` no longer shows any error, all ther errors I compliained about remaind.

Comment: Change this line in `PostFragment`:  `private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;` to `private PostAdapter adapter;` that will fix the "cannot resolve method" errors.  "self" is used in ParseAuthor because we don't have the author href anymore at this point, so author json -> _links -> self[0] -> href is the exact same as postitems json -> _links -> author[0] -> href.  Hope that makes sense.  We are getting the exact same author href, just from the author JSON because we don't have the one from the PostItem JSON.

Comment: Yes, it worked like charm but the workings of the code is all Greek to me. For the explanation of the `"self"` array, why didn't we just store the author href in a global variable and use it as a parameter for `adapter.putAuthor`?

Comment: A global variable can't be used for the `authorHref`.  Consider the case that you get four post items with four different authors.  Four different requests for author will be fired and `parseAuthor()` will be called four times.  How would we know which `authorHref` went with which `parseAuthor()`?  Having said that, there is a little simpler way to send the `authorHref` to `parseAuthor()` by having a `final` variable.  I will update the answer to show how to do that.  When I started Android it was strange to me, too.  The longer you keep at it the easier it gets.

Comment: Thanks both for the helpful answer and the explanation. I understand better now.